# Cypher variable path condition filtering

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The cypher does not support conditional filtering of variable paths. It can only be searched by sub-queries, but the efficiency of sub-queries is particularly low. How should it be optimized?

```
MATCH (account:Account{id:15393163051738})-[edge1:transfer]->(otherAccounts1:Account)
  WHERE edge1.transferDate>1276657248987 AND edge1.transferDate<1330135293550
WITH DISTINCT otherAccounts1 AS otherAccounts1
MATCH (account:Account{id:15393163051738})-[edge1:transfer]->()-[edge2:transfer]->(otherAccounts2:Account)
  WHERE edge1.transferDate>1276657248987 AND edge1.transferDate<1330135293550 AND edge2.transferDate>1276657248987 AND edge2.transferDate<1330135293550
WITH DISTINCT otherAccounts2 AS otherAccounts2, otherAccounts1
MATCH (account:Account{id:15393163051738})-[edge1:transfer]->()-[edge2:transfer]->()-[edge3:transfer]->(otherAccounts3:Account)
  WHERE edge1.transferDate>1276657248987 AND edge1.transferDate<1330135293550 AND edge2.transferDate>1276657248987 AND edge2.transferDate<1330135293550 AND edge3.transferDate>1276657248987 AND edge3.transferDate<1330135293550
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT otherAccounts1.id) + COLLECT(DISTINCT otherAccounts2.id) + COLLECT(otherAccounts3.id) as otherAccounts
RETURN otherAccounts
```

Comment: Do you have a index on transferDate and account id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
MATCH path=(account {id..})-[:transfer*1..2]->(otherAccount:Account))
WHERE ALL (edge IN rels(path) WHERE transferDate >  ...  AND .... )
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT otherAccount) AS otherAccounts
```

Comment: Can you please create another question for this, and try to elaborate? Including the (in)correct results?

Comment: I have another question. For the same node, I want to count the number of outgoing edges of his three types, the result of the subquery seems to be incorrect. Like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68588484/count-the-number-of-different-types-of-edges-of-a-node

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer:

MATCH path=(account:Account{id:15393163051738})-[:transfer*1..3]->(otherAccount:Account)
WHERE ALL (edge IN relationships(path) WHERE edge.transferDate > 1276657248987  AND edge.transferDate < 1330135293550 )
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT otherAccount) AS disOtherAccount