# Count the number of different types of edges of a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For the same node, I want to count the number of outgoing edges of his three types, the result of the subquery seems to be incorrect. Like this, note the fourth line and after

```
MATCH path=(account:Account{id:15393163051738})-[:transfer*1..3]->(otherAccount:Account)
WHERE ALL (edge IN relationships(path) WHERE edge.transferDate > 1276657248987  AND edge.transferDate < 1330135293550 )
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT otherAccount.id) AS disOtherAccount
MATCH (oAccount:Account)-[edge4:signUp]->(phone:Phone)
WHERE oAccount.id IN disOtherAccount AND edge4.signUpDate>1276657248987 AND edge4.signUpDate<1330135293550 AND phone.isBlocked=true
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT phone) AS phoneCount, disOtherAccount
MATCH (oAccount:Account)-[edge5:signIn]->(ip:IP)
WHERE oAccount.id IN disOtherAccount AND ip.signInDate>12766572489870 AND ip.signInDate<1330135293550 AND ip.isBlocked = TRUE
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS ipCount, disOtherAccount, phoneCount
MATCH (oAccount:Account)-[edge6:signIn]->(mac:MAC)
WHERE oAccount.id IN disOtherAccount AND mac.signInDate>127665724898700 AND mac.signInDate<1330135293550 AND mac.isBlocked = TRUE
RETURN phoneCount, ipCount, COUNT(DISTINCT mac) AS macCount
```

Comment: You seem not to be counting edges, but vertices

Comment: yeah, also vertices

Answer (score 0):

You have to carry along the original account in the WITH statement, so you can COUNT and COLLECT for each account.

Also, use OPTIONAL MATCH, otherwise you will get nothing in case the account does not have a phone , for example.